# Persistently ask question trying to find error or inconsistency in someone else's work?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a verb that could describe the action of persistently asking questions to try find an error or inconsistency in someone else's words or work to make them look bad?

Comment: 'Nitpicking' is probably not close enough, as you do not say that the interrogators succeed.

Answer (score 0):

**sharpshoot** is the word for this.

Merriam-Webster defines **sharpshooting** as

> accurate and usually unexpected attack (as in words)